# Why does Ionic prefix @Event names?

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs

Ionic don't prefix @Props, but they do prefix @Events. What's the reason?

When coding a library using StencilJs, what's stopping me from creating a MyTextInput component and using:

```
@Event() change: EventEmitter<string>;
```

instead of:

```
@Event() myChange: EventEmitter<string>;
```

Using the same event name as on a standard input would make the custom input more straight forward to use. What's the reasoning here? What am I missing? Why did Ionic name the change event `ionChange` for the input component?

Comment: Have you tested this? My guess is that this would lead to two events being fired, the native and the custom one, and since they bubble any listeners would also fire twice.

Comment: I have tested it using the Angular wrapper generated by stencil, and the event is fired only once in the case of an input. I don't see anything abnormal

Comment: Just tested it using directly the Web Component just in case, and the event is fired only once as well